# Android Studio debug does not log Firestore Database Reading

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

When running Android Studio Debug mode, it will not log my messages and will not add any rooms to my LinkedList when running the following code below. However, it runs perfectly when running it normally. I am running it through a connected samsung phone (not an emulator).

Does anyone know the reason why this happens?

```
    final LinkedList<String> rooms = new LinkedList<>();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference refDb = database.getReference();


    refDb.child("Room").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting search");
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                int i = 0;
                for(DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "room: " + d.getKey());
                    System.out.println("room: " + d.getKey().toString());
                    rooms.add(d.getKey().toString());
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "->onCancelled");
            System.out.println("room: cancelled");
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does this line `Log.d(TAG, "room: " + d.getKey());` print?

Comment: "SearchActivity: room:CB1104400"

Comment: Then why do you say that the messages aren't logged? I see that you have the correct output, right?

Comment: This is only logged in normal mode. Nothing is logged when running it debugged mode. "When running Android Studio Debug mode, it will not log my messages" & "However, it runs perfectly when running it normally"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could realize, your app is responding accordingly, but the `Log.d(TAG, "room: " + d.getKey());` is not printing in your **Logcat**, right?

If yes, you just have to choose the device in your **Logcat** and your physical device must be connected to your PC via USB cable.

Good Luck!